# Create foreign key objects inside serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I've two model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Books(models.Model)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='books_author')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now, I need to create an author and it's related books in a single request inside create serializer. The incoming data would look something like this:

```
{
 "author": "John Doe"
 "books":[
     {
        "name": "Life of Pie"
     },
     {
        "name": "Lord of the rings"      
     }
  ]
 }
```

How can I do it without using a for loop inside the create serializer?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested serializers are read-only, you will need to override the `create` method, and the simplest method is to use a for loop.

```py
# serializers.py

class BooksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = ('name',)


class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    books = BooksSerializer(source='books_author', many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        books_data = validated_data.pop('books_author')
        author = Author.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for book in books_data:
            Books.objects.create(author=author, **book)
        return author

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name', 'books')
```

Note that I used "name" and not "author" as it seems more logical, so you'd need to use the following body:

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "books": [
        {
            "name": "Life of Pie"
        },
        {
            "name": "Lord of the rings"
        }
    ]
}
```

The same goes for the `update` method.
More details in [the official documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

On a side note, I'd:

- rename `Books`to `Book` (models.py)
- change `related_name='books_author'` by `related_name='books'` (models.py)
- rename `BooksSerializer` to `BookSerializer` (serializers.py)
- replace `books = BooksSerializer(source='books_author', many=True)` by `books = BooksSerializer(many=True)`(serializers.py)

This would make your code more readable.